# How to reference a state within a state declaration in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, chatterbot

I have a class which has a steps array as a state.

An object in this array is a component and requires me to pass a state into it as a property.

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);

this.state = {
     steps:[
          {
               id: '1',
               component: <ABC mem={this.state.memory} />
          }
     ],

     memory: "Testing"
}

}
```

It gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, It will give error because by `{this.state.memory}` is not yet initialized.

State is getting initialized for the **First Time** inside Constructor and State will be undefined by that time.

Not sure your use case, but if you want to keep a reference to different components inside an array and render it later by passing props, you can certainly use a better way either by utilizing [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) or directly rendering it.

Here is the working example :

https://codepen.io/raviroshan/pen/ZxNeWX?editors=0010